# How can I add style to a list element which contains a visited link?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using Stylebot for Chrome to override some styling on a webpage I often visit. What I like to acheve is to hide elements in a list which contain links I already visited.

So i have a `<tr>` which has the class `table-row` and I want to hide all `table-row`s which contain a visited link (`a:visited`).

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS solution or javascript?

Comment: Is a jQuery solution useful?

Comment: Set up a fiddle with 3 or 4 rows...

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible, for security reasons. If you try to determine whether a link is `:visited` by the presentation style, the browser will lie to you.

Comment: Whatever I can tamper with using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not even with JavaScript.  `:visited` is a special class that has privacy safe-guards bound to it.  It won't return any elements in a DOM selector query.  To do it with CSS, you would need the elusive ancestor selector, which doesn't currently exist.  Even if it did, the same privacy safe-guards would probably prevent it from working.

See [Selectors API, Privacy Considerations](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#privacy) for mor information.

Comment: `.list-row a:visited {
    color: white;
}` this is already working but I don't want to highlight the links but hide the list elements containing them.

Comment: @Adam: yes, I understand what you're asking, but it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide or change the list elements containing a:visited, but you can change their color.

I have a same problem, then I changed all their color to background's color. It's here, but you can't see them.